# Is it possible to add a class to an image field of a node wise

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I have a content type that has title, body, image etc. I am displaying the Title, image with caption and body using Manage Display. But here there is no option to align (Left, Right, Center) the image. How to align the image node wise.

OR

Is it possible to add a class to an image field of a node wise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked the already built-in classes drupal adds to fields in the HTML? That is the way I style a single content view.
2. Is this https://drupal.org/node/1795294 the module? In the description they explain how to add a class.

PD: I wanted to leave a comment but do not have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Francisco has the right idea. Use Display Suite to wrap a div around your displayed image, and put your css class there.

Another option is to use the insert module and style the image any way you want after inserting it into another field.